# Changing a variable's value based on another variable in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, global-variables

first let me say I am trying very hard to learn PHP, and the more I learn, the more I want to learn and use the language.  I'm primarily an HTML5/CSS3 coder, and am trying to make my sites more efficient by using PHP.

Here is my current dilemma.  I am attempting to utilize variables to change values as required.  At the beginning of each page file I have declared the page name, called my functions file and called head and header functions:

```
<?php
    $page = 'contact';
    include('functions.php');
    head();
    header();
?>
```

A slight variation of this is included in all page files.  Things are good.

Now, in my functions.php I have a variable for the meta title value, i.e. `$title`, and have declared it as a global.

How do I change the value of this variable based on the value of the $page variable?  Here is what I have added to the functions.php file, but I am quite sure it is incorrect, as it is not working:

```
$title = array {
    if ($page == 'contact') {
        echo 'Contact Us';
    }
}
```

I'm not just looking for the right code, but an explanation if possible.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store all titles in an associative array:

```
$TITLES = array(
    'contact' => 'Contact Us',
    'home' => 'Welcome',
);

$title = "Some Default Title"; 

if(isset($TITLES[$page])){ //check to see if we have a specific title set up 

    $title = $TITLES[$page]; //override it if it is set 

}
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what Jason OOO was advising in his comment, so thank you for explaining rosscowar.  I think I would lean to this method more than the switch, as it seems more compact.  Thanks for your help!  This is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create an associative array that contains pages as keys and titles as values, then you can get the value such as:

```
$titles = array('Home' => 'Welcome to Home', 'contact' => 'Contact Us');

if(array_key_exists($page, $titles)){
 echo $titkes[$page];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function with an argument and then use [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) cases to check the variable value and return the appropriate text.

```
function pageTitle($var) {
    switch ($var)
    {
    case "contact":
      return "Contact Us";
      break;
    case "about":
      return "About Us";
      break;
    .
    .
    .
    default:
      return "Default"; //default case
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<?php
    $page = 'contact';
    include('functions.php');
    head();

    echo PageTitle('contact'); //should echo 'Contact Us'
    header();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd recommend is perhaps a `switch case` statement to store all of the possible types.

```
switch($page){
    case "contact":
        $title = "Contact Us";
        break;
    case "about":
        $title = "About Us";
        break;
    default:
        $title = "Default Title";
        break;
}
```